# Cascading multiple models

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, model-associations

I'm deleting a Place and it's cascading the rows of PlaceUpload, but I also would like to cascade the rows of Match and TagCostumer while I am deleting a Place. How can I do that?

```
class Place < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :place_uploads
end

class PlaceUpload < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :place
    has_many :matches
    has_many :tags_customers
end

class TagsCustomer < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :place_upload
    belongs_to :tag
end

class Match < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :place_upload
    belongs_to :customer
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to use destroy and create a callback to automatically do a deep cascading.

```
class Place < ActiveRecord::Base

    before_destroy :delete_children_objects

    has_many :place_uploads, :dependent => :destroy

    protected

        def delete_children_objects
            @places = PlaceUpload.where(place_id: id)
            @places.each do |place|
                TagsCustomer.where(place_upload_id: place.id).destroy_all
                Match.where(place_upload_id: place.id).destroy_all
            end
        end
end
```